# Cassini oval plotting related isues

Tags: plotting, regions, parametric-functions, regionplot

### **PART 1**

The parametric equation mentioned in the webpage, [Eggs, melons, and peanuts - Cassini Oval](http://lemur.cmp.uea.ac.uk/Research/ivis/backup/PhD/Latest/Paul%20Bourke%20Screenshots/Eggs,%20melons,%20and%20peanuts%20-%20Cassini%20Oval.htm), for the Cassini oval is given by

```
Wall[{a_, b_}, 
   t_] := {Cos[t]*Sqrt[a^2 Cos[2*t] + Sqrt[(b^4 - a^2*Sin[2*t]^2)]], 
   Sin[t]*Sqrt[a^2 Cos[2*t] + Sqrt[(b^4 - a^2*Sin[2*t]^2)]]};
```

where, `c = a^2 Cos[2*t] \[PlusMinus] Sqrt[(b^4 - a^2*Sin[2*t]^2)];`

> Note: b cannot be 0
>
> 1. When a < b the parameter t ranges from 0 to 2 Pi
> 2. When a = b the curve reduces to r^2 = a^2 Cos (2 t)
> 3. When a > b each loop is defined in two parts, one using the positive version of c above, and the other using the negative version.
>    The parameter t ranges from - 0.5 ArcSin (b^2/a^2) to 0.5 ArcSin
>    (b^2/a^2).

While plotting, for `b>a`, the results are coming as expected. However, for `b<a`, incomplete circles are forming even if I'm using the 3rd case as mentioned above.
[image]

I'm making a mistake in defining the loops by taking +ve and -ve values of `c`, I guess.
Here is my sample code using the -ve value of c for plotting

```
Wall1[{a_, b_}, 
  t_] := {Cos[t]*
   Sqrt[-(a^2 Cos[2*t] - Sqrt[(b^4 - a^2*Sin[2*t]^2)])], 
  Sin[t]*Sqrt[-(a^2 Cos[2*t] - Sqrt[(b^4 - a^2*Sin[2*t]^2)])]}

ParametricPlot[{Wall[{1, Sqrt[1.35]}, t], Wall1[{1, Sqrt[0.5]}, t], 
  Wall[{1, Sqrt[0.5]}, t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Darker[Green], Blue}]
```

[image]

Please help solve this issue of plotting the graph using `ParametricPlot`. The desired graphs should come as this
[image]

### PART 2

In Cartesian Co-ordinates, the region is defined by

```
\[GothicCapitalR]0[x_, y_, a_, 
   b_] := ((x - a)^2 + y^2) ((x + a)^2 + y^2) - b^2;
```

However, the `ParametricPlot` and `ContourPlot` give slightly different results as shown below for `b>a`.

```
Show[ParametricPlot[Wall1[{1, Sqrt[1.375]}, t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red}], 
 ContourPlot[\[GothicCapitalR]0[x, y, 1, Sqrt[1.35]] == 0, {x, -2, 
   2}, {y, -1, 1}]]
```

[image]

Why is this happening? And how to resolve this issue and get the same shape?

Please help me out.

Comment: Why don't you just plot both branches, namely the one with + and the one with –? `Wall[{a_, b_}, t_] := Wall[{a, b}, t] = FullSimplify@{{Cos[t]*Sqrt[a^2 Cos[2*t] + Sqrt[(b^4 - a^2*Sin[2*t]^2)]], Sin[t]*Sqrt[a^2 Cos[2*t] + Sqrt[(b^4 - a^2*Sin[2*t]^2)]]},{Cos[t]*Sqrt[a^2 Cos[2*t] - Sqrt[(b^4 - a^2*Sin[2*t]^2)]], Sin[t]*Sqrt[a^2 Cos[2*t] - Sqrt[(b^4 - a^2*Sin[2*t]^2)]]}};`

Comment: @Domen, I did not know that I could define a function like this. Thank you. However, it doesn't work while plotting the graph. I mean the desired plot is not coming. `ParametricPlot[{Wall[{1, Sqrt[0.9]}, t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]`

Comment: Try `Clear[Wall]` first. [It works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDGxE.png) for me.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 12.0 on a Linux system. Could that be a reason for not geeting the grapph? Because, I have used Clear[Wall]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to plot both branches, the one with $+$ and the one with $-$ inside square root. You can do this with one `ParametricPlot` by simply plotting both of the branches at the same time.

```
Clear[Wall];
Wall[{a_, b_}, t_] := Module[{
    c1 = a^2 Cos[2*t],
    c2 = Sqrt[(b^4 - a^2*Sin[2*t]^2)]},
    {
     {Cos[t], Sin[t]} Sqrt[c1 + c2],
     {Cos[t], Sin[t]} Sqrt[c1 - c2]
    }
   ];

ParametricPlot[
 Table[Wall[{1, b}, t], {b, 0.2, 1.5, .2}], {t, -2 Pi, 2 π}, 
 PlotHighlighting -> None, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

Note that you may need to increase `PlotPoints` even further for smaller `b`s.

As for the discrepany with `ContourPlot`, two issues:

1. You are using $b=1.375$ in `ParametricPlot` and $b=1.35$ in `ContourPlot`.
2. There is probably a mistake somewhere in the derivation on the page, mixing $b$ and $b^2$. The curves match if you use $b^2$ instead of $b$ in `ContourPlot`:

```
R0[x_, y_, a_, b_] := ((x - a)^2 + y^2) ((x + a)^2 + y^2) - b^2;
With[{b = 1.375},
 Show[ParametricPlot[Wall[{1, Sqrt[b]}, t], {t, 0, 2 π}], 
  ContourPlot[R0[x, y, 1, b] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]]]
```

[image]