# How can I simulate merging of droplets pressed between two slides?

Tags: graphics, regions, animation, simulation

I'd like to study the evolution and merging of multiple droplet outlines, while confined and pressed between two planparallel slides.

Does anyone have an idea how to code an interactive script by MMA with the option to "squeeze the slides" in order to view droplet (parameterized by position and volumina) diameter increasing (first) and merging (second)?

Here is a graphic with timesteps I have in mind:
[image: Merging Droplets]

Comment: Is this only for visualization purposes, or is there some underlying model about how the two circles are merged? (Namely, you can draw different curves connecting the two circles.) Since you want to "study" this process, you probably want to base this on some precise model.

Comment: I do not see any pressing slides on your images. Droplets do not need any pressing to merge together just making them touch each other is enough to cause merging.

Comment: I am voting to close. There is just too little information. Open ended problem. No prior work.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a starting point using function `Wall` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/296109/53172). The function should be adjusted if a constant volume (area) of droplets is required throughout the animation.

```
Wall[{a_, b_}, t_] := 
  Module[{c1 = a^2 Cos[2*t], 
    c2 = Sqrt[(b^4 - a^2*Sin[2*t]^2)]}, {{Cos[t], Sin[t]} Sqrt[
      c1 + c2], {Cos[t], Sin[t]} Sqrt[c1 - c2]}];

Animate[ParametricPlot[Wall[{1, b}, t]/b, {t, -2 Pi, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotPoints -> 200, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> 3.5], {b, 3, 0.2}]
```

[image]